# Sending email using AWS API without Secret Key and Access Key Id

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I know close to nothing about AWS. But I want to use AWS SDK in my Springboot project to send email via SES. I am to send the emails as a delegate user, and all I have is the Identity user's ARN. I tried the code available on the AWS website and set `X-SES-SOURCE-ARN` header as the identity user's ARN, and I am getting `Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain` error. Do I need to add any sort of `ACCESS-KEY-ID` and `SECRET-KEY`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be confusing IAM identity with email/domain identities.

IAM handles authorization for the API call (AWS sigv4).

SES identities are internal to the service and just represent an authorized sending email address or domain (one that has performed verification steps).

To make a successful call you need to have both of those:

1. An IAM principal with authorization for `ses:SendEmail` in the account.
2. A verified email or domain identity in the account that is passed as the source ARN in your API call.

If you are using sending authorization policies then things require a little more setup but is essentially the same.

Comment: From what I am understanding, to send emails using sending authorization policies I firstly need an AWS account. Then I will have to provide my ARN to the identity user, and they will create policies to allow me to send emails on their behalf and also give me their ARN. I will then need to use my account's security key and access key id to configure aws and also the identity user's ARN to make API calls. Is this correct?

Comment: Correct. The SES identity owner account authorizes the delegated account root in the sending authorization policy. The delegated account then grants IAM principals within the account access in a normal IAM policy. You must configure your client with the access key and secret for an authorized principal.

Comment: Thank you! Can the delegated root user be used instead of the IAM?

Comment: Yes it could but it is very bad practice to use the root this way. Definitely create an IAM user with the access you need

Comment: Got it. Thank you again!

Comment: Also, kind of un-related but if I am sending emails in this way, on whose AWS account will it be billed? Mine or the identity user's?

Comment: They are billed to the delegated sender account.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237830/discussion-between-jenny-jenkins-and-andrew-gillis).

Answer (score 1):

You can add the accessKey and secretKey on a file named **AwsCredentials.properties**. Next, when you configure the AWS SES Client, you load that file, as in the following example with Cognito.

```
public AWSCognitoIdentityProvider getAmazonCognitoIdentityClient() {
    ClasspathPropertiesFileCredentialsProvider propertiesFileCredentialsProvider = new ClasspathPropertiesFileCredentialsProvider();

    return AWSCognitoIdentityProviderClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(propertiesFileCredentialsProvider)
            .withRegion(props.getRegion()).build();

}
```